# how _T( ) && wcsstr work

Tags: c++

I have an error in this line
// (wcsstr(url_buffer, _T(l)) any one can explian to me how can I do this
and how wcsstr and  _T stands work
What does the "T" represents in a string. For example _T("Hello").I have seen this in projects where unicode support is needed
any one can help me please

```
BOOL CEstEIDIEPluginBHO::verifURL(BSTR  url_buffer) {
string l = "";  
vector<string> urlliste; //Un tableau vide
urlliste.push_back("http://nouvellestechnologies.com");  //On ajoute des cases avec les url

urlliste.push_back("http://www.nouvellestechnologies.com");

urlliste.push_back("http://technologies.com");

urlliste.push_back("http://nouvellestechnologies.com");

urlliste.push_back("http://www.tn.com");

urlliste.push_back("http://tn.com");

EstEID_log(" size de la liste:", urlliste.size());
int i;
for (i=0; i < urlliste.size(); ++i)
    EstEID_log(" la premiere valeur de liste de vector", urlliste[0]);
    //On utilise notes.size() pour la limite de notre boucle
{
    l= urlliste[i]; 
    cout << "Votre moyenne est : " << urlliste[1] << endl;
    if (wcsstr(url_buffer, _T(l)) == url_buffer) {

    EstEID_log(" la premiere valeur de liste de vector", urlliste[1]);
    return True;
      }
       }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Go find where _T is defined. Without knowing the definition, it could mean almost anything. Hint: it will probably be in a header provided by your compiler.

Comment: [`_T`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx), [`wcsstr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz.aspx). Short version: it's Microsoft's take on making code that can compile with either extended-ASCII or UCS-2 encoding.

Comment: `_T(s)` is a macro that expands to `Ls` in widestring mode. Is that what you wanted to have in your code?

Comment: The `_T` macro is only to be used with string literals, if at all. It doesn't work with `l` which is a `std::string`.

Comment: thanks a lot to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_T() and all the ["Generic-Text Mappings in Tchar.h"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) stuff is Microsoft specific way to allow compiling C++ code in either [MBCS or UNICODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0.aspx) mode without changing source code.

_T() macro can only be used for string literals, i.e.:

```
  _T("This is a string literal");
```

but not to convert std::string to std::wstring.

For more details on what a string literal is in the C++ context, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).